# How to advise someone about the danger of a television failling from his arms

Tags: expressions, translation

Does the sentence "You drop the television!" express the purpose of advising someone about the danger (of the television falling from his arms) or the fact of not being able to believe that someone dropped the television?

The google translator suggest this answer: *You drop the television!* as a translation of «¡Que se te cae el televisor!» But it sounds like if you were dropping the television on purpose.

Comment: There is a clear English question here.  I've edited to make the translation aspect secondary, and the primary question "how do I say this in English".  There is a clear attempt to find the answer independently, and a suggested sentence (it doesn't matter where it comes from). The Spanish might help some people understand what you intend to mean, but it should not be the main purpose of the question.  I've used your own (incorrect) language to ask the question rather than re-write.

Comment: @JamesK Could you please tell me what is incorrect in my question? "I've used your own (incorrect) language". Thanks.

Comment: Well, for example the use of "advertise" is non-standard, and there are some agreement errors "The google translator suggest". The spelling of "falling" is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You drop the television." is the "indicative present tense", It would rare to use this in English with the verb "drop". It would be only be used when an action starts and finishes at the same time as the speech occurs.

So it could be used for commentary "Ronaldo kicks the ball" but unless you are standing and describing to a second person their actions, this is not correct.

If you intend to warn someone of possible consequences then use the future. There are several ways to talk about the future, but using the "will" modal is simplest.

> You'll drop the television (if you don't hold it carefully).

Which you could combine with some kind of exclamation "Watch out!" or "Take care!", for example.